# Find all <a href>link</a> in a string with java regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a String which contains some url how i can find all the href with a regular expression?

```
<a href="http://www.amazon.it/Die-10-Symphonien-Orchesterlieder-Sinfonie-Complete/dp/B003LQSHBO/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1440101590&sr=8-2&keywords=mahler">prodotto di prova</a>
```

Now i have this which find all amazon links now i need to add also the href to this regex:

```
 String regex="(http|www\\.)(amazon|AMAZON)\\.(com|it|uk|fr|de)\\/(?:gp\\/product|gp\\/product\\/glance|[^\\/]+\\/dp|dp|[^\\/]+\\/product-reviews)\\/([^\\/]{10})";
```

Comment: What's expected result exactly?

Comment: i need a regex that takes all the href that contains amazon url. my regex works but i don't know how to add ahref in a regex

Comment: If you have found all the amazon links, then why you need to find them with <a></a> parts? Can't you add that part for already taken URLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pattern works for me in Java: (IDEONE [here](http://ideone.com/uy7mMP))

```
String input = "<a href=\"http://www.amazon.it/Die-10-Symphonien-Orchesterlieder-Sinfonie-Complete/dp/B003LQSHBO/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1440101590&sr=8-2&keywords=mahler\">prodotto di prova</a>\"";
String pattern = "href=(?<link>['\\\"](?:https?:\\/\\/)?(?:www\\.)?(?:amazon|AMAZON)\\.(?:com|it|uk|fr|de)\\/(?<product>:gp\\/product|gp\\/product\\/glance|[^\\/]+\\/dp|dp|[^\\/]+\\/product-reviews)\\/(?<productID>[^\\/]{10})\\/(?<queryString>.*?)\\\")";

Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(input);

if (m.find( )) {
 System.out.println("Amazon link: " + m.group(0) );
 System.out.println("product: " + m.group("product") );
 System.out.println("productID: " + m.group("productID"));
 System.out.println("querystring: " + m.group("queryString"));
} else {
 System.out.println("NO MATCH");
}
```

output:

- Amazon link:
  href="http://www.amazon.it/Die-10-Symphonien-Orchesterlieder-Sinfonie-Complete/dp/B003LQSHBO/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1440101590&sr=8-2&keywords=mahler"
- product: Die-10-Symphonien-Orchesterlieder-Sinfonie-Complete/dp
- productID: B003LQSHBO
- querystring: ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1440101590&sr=8-2&keywords=mahler

Java's rules for backslashes and escapes in strings are absolutely infuriating to me and I never get it right. You may find it helpful to go to http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html and enter a regex, which it will convert into a java string with the proper escapes. (I couldn't get mine working until I did this!)

Comment: how i can do if i want link from href to product id only?

Comment: if you try with this link <a href="http://www.amazon.it/gp/product/B015Z1YACC">product</a> not work

Comment: @FilomenaDelSorbo: updated. make (?<querystring>regex) part optional :https://regex101.com/r/jC1jN5/1